# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.localVideoref')

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to learn about WebRTC and p2p com with React JS. I just want to see the video of the computer camera on localhost but it gives me this error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.localVideoref')
(anonymous function) — App.js:18
promiseReactionJob
```

You can see my App.js below:

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.localVideoref = React.createRef()
  }
  render(){
    const constraints = { audio: false, video: true }
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
    .then(function(stream) {
      console.log('stream: ' , stream)
      this.localVideoref.current.srcObject = stream
    })
    .catch(function(e) {
      console.log('getUserMedia Error: ', e)
    });
    return (
      <div>
          <video ref={this.localVideoref} autoPlay></video>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

I saw that mediaDevices only works on secure connection, so I installed a new certificate to my localhost and run the project as HTTPS:enable but nothing changed. Using https:localhost is not the answer for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll post this with hooks because it's what I use now.

It's best to move the asynchronous code to an effect (or in your case, probably `componentDidMount`) and let the video re-render when the source is available.

This worked for me:

```
const App = () => {
  const localVideoRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!localVideoRef) return;
    const constraints = { audio: false, video: true };

    const setSource = async () => {
      const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);
      localVideoRef.current.srcObject = stream;
    };
    setSource();
  }, [localVideoRef]);

  return (
    <div>
      <video ref={localVideoRef} autoPlay></video>
    <div>
  )
}
```